# Discord.js v14 Button Emoji Error When Putting Emoji ID

Tags: discord.js

I included Emoji For Button In My Code IDK The Reason It Crashes Can Someone Say Me The Solution

I Searched Internet And Also Another Stackoverflow Discussion But Didn't Found A Fix

IDK WHAT TO SAY MORE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
  'intents': [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  'partials': [Partials.Channel]
});

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`${client.user.username} Is Online!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`>>rank`, { type: "WATCHING" });
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  const btn1 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('btn1')
    .setLabel('Click Me!')
    .setStyle('Primary')

    const btn2 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setLabel('YT')
    .setEmoji("<1008747826714521610>")
    .setStyle('Link')
    .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/c/himisa')

    const btn3 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('btn2')
    .setLabel('Click Me!')
    .setStyle('Success')

    if (message.content === 'hi'){
      return message.channel.send({
        content: 'HI' , components:[new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(btn1,btn2,btn3)]
      })
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if(interaction.isButton){
    await interaction.deferUpdate();
    if(interaction.customId === 'btn1'){
      await interaction.channel.send('Um Hello');
    }
  }
});


client.login('SUPER SECRET TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Something To Fix This!
If You Are Using Default Emoji Use Unicode Emoji Like This 
If You Wanna Use A Custom Emoji You Have To Include :hi:123456789 Like This It Worked For Me
Also Remember To Not To Put The <>

```js
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ActivityType } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
  'intents': [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  'partials': [Partials.Channel]
});

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`${client.user.username} Is Online!`);
    client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  const btn1 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('btn1')
    .setLabel('Click Me!')
    .setStyle('Primary')

    const btn2 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setLabel('YT')
    .setEmoji(':hi:1010402480074539109')
    .setStyle('Link')
    .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/c/himisa')

    const btn3 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('btn2')
    .setLabel('Click Me!')
    .setStyle('Success')

    if (message.content === 'hi'){
      return message.channel.send({
        content: 'HI' , components:[new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(btn1,btn2,btn3)]
      })
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if(interaction.isButton){
    await interaction.deferUpdate();
    if(interaction.customId === 'btn1'){
      interaction.followUp({ content: 'Um Hello', ephemeral: true });
    }
  }
});


client.login('SUPER SECRET TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only supposed to put the emoji ID there, remove the < > and it should work.

```js
 .setEmoji("1008747826714521610")
```

Source: [The official discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#emoji-buttons)

Comment: It didn't really worked did u tried?

Answer (score 0):

discord emojis put the name of the emoji and the id when sending it to chat like this:

**<:emoji_name:0123456789>**

This is the format you should use in your code as well otherwise discord has no idea which emoji you want to send.

Comment: It didn't worked too
Maybe I need another intent?

Comment: try it without the <> if that doesn’t work i will test it out myself

Comment: Doesn't Work Bro

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried Using the Action Builder With the buttons
I'm from Cody Dimensions The Server u requested help from
Can u try your code like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = ("discord.js")

const client = new Client({
  'intents': [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  'partials': [Partials.Channel]
});

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`${client.user.username} Is Online!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`>>rank`, { type: "WATCHING" });
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
      .addComponents(
    const btn1 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('btn1')
    .setLabel('Click Me!')
    .setStyle('Primary')

    const btn2 = new ButtonBuilder()
    .setLabel('YT')
    .setEmoji("<1008747826714521610>")
    .setStyle('Link')
    .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/c/himisa')

        const btn3 = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('btn2')
        .setLabel('Click Me!')
        .setStyle('Success')

    );
    if (message.content === 'hi'){
      return message.channel.send({ content: 'HI' components: [row]}))
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if(interaction.isButton){
    await interaction.deferUpdate();
    if(interaction.customId === 'btn1'){
      await interaction.channel.send('Um Hello');
    }
  }
});


client.login('SUPER SECRET TOKEN');
```

Comment: Bro it crash my bot syntax errs can u pls fix im new

Comment: it says const not defined

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).